# I'm trying to make a virtual store (I just started learning c++)

Tags: c++, codeblocks

so I'm trying to make some kind of virtual store just to test what I can do, I used  the following strings: sProdus(sProduct),sPretFinal(sFinalPrice),sCantitate(sQuantity)

The problem is that I can't do math with strings, and when I change them to int variables the if statements will not work. I tried removing the " , changing the == into =.

I don't know what else I could do, could you tell me?

(When I run the following code and enter the quantity, it will always say 'Final Price' and then it shows nothing)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

 int a=29999,b=2,c=2.5,

string sProdus;    // (sProduct)
string sCantitate;   // (sQuantity)
string sPretFinal;   // (sFinalPrice)

sPretFinal=sProdus*sCantitate;

cout <<"Bun venit in magazinul lui Bogdan, ce doriti sa cumparati?";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout <<"Puteti cumpara:televizor Phillips 1920x1280 (a), mere(b), banane(b)";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout <<"Apasati litera corespunzatoare produsului pentru a vedea pretul acestuia";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;

cout<<"Produsul ales: ";cin>> sProdus;




if(sProdus=a){cout<<"Pretul televizorului Phillips 1920x1280: 29,999 RON";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Cantitatea: ";cin>>sCantitate;

cout<<"Pretul final este:"<<sPretFinal;
}


if(sProdus=b){cout<<"Pretul unui mar: 2 RON";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Cantitatea: ";cin>>sCantitate;

cout<<"Pretul final este:";sPretFinal;
}


if(sProdus=c){cout<<"Pretul unei banane:2.50 RON";
cout<<endl;
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Cantitatea: ";cin;sCantitate;

cout<<"Pretul final este:";sPretFinal;
}
if(sProdus !=c && sProdus !=a && sProdus !=b)
{
   cout<<"Ne cerem scuze, dar acest produs nu exista in magazin";
   cout<<endl;
}
}
```

I would really love if someone could help me on this :) I hope I was specific enough. :)
I am using CodeBlocks btw.

Answer (score 5):

You have many errors in your code...

1) CodeBlocks is an [IDE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment), not a programming language. The program you post is in [c++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B).

2) `=` is an assignment operator and `==` is a relational operator (see [c++ operators](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/)). In your case, in the `if` statement, you have to use `==`.

3) When you declare multiple variables, you also have to end your line with a `;` like the others (see [declare multiple variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6838416/3442166)).

4) If you want to have decimals in your variable, you have to use the `double` or `float` types (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2386882/3442166) for the difference), not `int`. In your case you can use `float`.

5) Don't name your variables `a`, `b` or `c`, but use explicit names. Please see [this example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Readability).

6) You declare `string` variables and you do calculations with that. The [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/) class is used for store multiple characters, not number to do calculations.

7) You declare your string variables **without** value :

```
string sProdus;    // (sProduct)
string sCantitate;   // (sQuantity)
string sPretFinal;   // (sFinalPrice)
```

And just after you do calculations with these variables :

```
sPretFinal=sProdus*sCantitate;
```

You can't use the content of a variable before you assign it a value.

8) Finally, please indent your code. [Artistic style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/) can help you if you want to do this automatically.

So I think before doing this program, you have to learn the basics of `c++`. You have a lot of free tutorial on the net that can help you to learn c++.