# How does comma separator in these declarations work in C++?

Tags: c++

The following declarations that include the comma are not clear to me;  about how the left side variables are mapped to the right side values. Therefore what would be the values assigned to the left side variables in each case?

Declaration 1:

```
long int x, y, z = d[0], k, len;
```

Declaration 2:

```
long int x, y, z = d[0], k;
```

(consider the `long int d[100]` array is initiated earlier and the values are assigned.)

Comment: What exactly are you confused about? The first declaration creates 5 `long ints`, while the second one creates 4.

Comment: What exactly confuses you? Those declarations refer to the 1st element declared in the `d` array.

Comment: A good idea to avoid confusion is to declare each variable separately. Saving characters were *possibly* good for K&R having a 10 characters/second interface for their [Teletype terminal](https://edition.cnn.com/2011/10/14/tech/innovation/dennis-ritchie-obit-bell-labs/index.html).

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838408/how-can-i-declare-and-define-multiple-variables-in-one-line-using-c

Comment: Flagged for _off-topic_ closure as _unclear_.

Comment: "I'm confused" is _not_ a clear programming question.

Comment: _@DaminduLiyanage_ And never use uninitialized variables BTW!

Comment: @AnonMail that's what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Oh no, this is so stupid there is no left or right side. This is a declaration separated by the comma and one variable given the value. This made my day. I just looked at it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

```
long int x, y, z = d[0], k, len;
```

This declares 5 variables, all are `long int`.

`x`, `y`, `k` and `len` are uninitialized.

`z` is initialized with the value of `d[0]`.

Maybe it's easier to understand the declaration if you write it like this:

```
long int x, 
         y, 
         z = d[0], 
         k, 
         len;
```

Comment: _"Maybe it's easier to understand ..."_ I'm still biased if this (simple formatting)  is good advice. Mentioning _better practice_ to use separate variable declarations (especially in regards of pointers or references) should be worth it.

Comment: @TheDude, Best practice is to write clear code.  To me, the above is more clear than what you suggest.

Comment: Wait! Having separate variable declarations is _less clear_ than simply breaking down _multiline_ variable declarations? Seriously?

Comment: Yes, I think so.  You don't think so.  So my opinion is not the same as your opinion.  Big deal.