# How does a comma separation function when declaring variables

Tags: c++, c, gcc, gcc-warning

I had made an error in my code at one point when I forgot to end a variable initialization with a semicolon and instead had put a comma. However, to my surprise it never returned an error and the code worked like normal.

Therefore I was wondering how this works ? I simplified my code by writing the below code;

```
uint32_t randomfunction_wret()
{
  printf("(%d:%s) - \n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
  return 6;
}

uint32_t randomfunction()
{
  printf("(%d:%s) - \n", __LINE__, __FILE__);
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t val32 = 3, randomfunction_wret(), valx = 6, randomfunction();

    printf("(%d:%s) - %u %u\n", __LINE__, __FILE__, val32, valx);

   return 0;
}
```

When executed is returns;

```
(43:test.c) - 3 6
```

I am very shocked that there is no error when I have functions separated in my initialization. However the functions were not even being called.

============== UPDATED

How about if the code was as follows, from what I see, now each function is called;

```
int main()
{
    uint32_t val32;

    val32 = 3, randomfunction_wret(), randomfunction();

    printf("(%d:%s) - %u \n", __LINE__, __FILE__, val32);

   return 0;
}
```

Output would be

```
(23:test.c) - 
(29:test.c) - 
(38:test.c) - 3
```

Comment: It's simply Undefined Behavior not to return from a function that is declared to return. Undefined Behavior means literally anything can happen, and that includes appearing to work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I declare and define multiple variables in one line using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838408/how-can-i-declare-and-define-multiple-variables-in-one-line-using-c)

Comment: @alterigel while that is true, this is not the immediate cause of OP's confusion.

Comment: @alterigel It's only undefined behavior if the return value of that function is used in an expression.  If not, there's no UB.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line

```
uint32_t val32 = 3, randomfunction_wret(), valx = 6, randomfunction();
```

is equivalent to;

```
uint32_t val32 = 3;                // Defines and initializes the variable.
uint32_t randomfunction_wret();    // Re-declares the function. Nothing else is done.
uint32_t valx = 6;                 // Defines and initializes the variable.
uint32_t randomfunction();         // Re-declares the function. Nothing else is done.
```

The variables used in the function are properly defined and initialized. Hence, the function works without any problem.

---

Just as an aside, the implementation of `randomfunction()` does not have a `return` statement. Using it will cause undefined behavior.

---

#### Update, in response to the edited post.

Due to [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), the line

```
val32 = 3, randomfunction_wret(), randomfunction();
```

is equivalent to:

```
(val32 = 3), randomfunction_wret(), randomfunction();
```

All the sub-expressions of the comma separated expression are evaluated. Hence, the functions `randomfunction_wret` and `randomfunction` are called and their return values are discarded.

Comment: Small caveat - `randomfunction` exposes undefined behavior, probably worth to add to the answer.

Comment: Added an extra part to question if you would know that. Thank you very much!