# Issue with variable values in C (huge numbers)

Tags: c, integer, pre-increment

I'm just start to learn C and I came across with an exercise to count the number of new lines(\n), blank spaces and tabs(\t) in stdin.

The question is,

Why:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int c, nl, ns, nt = 0;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {

        if (c == '\n') {

            ++nl;

        }

        else if (c == '\t') {

            ++nt;
           
        }
        else if (c == ' ') {

            ++ns;

        }

    }

    printf("Lines: %d, Tabs: %d, Spaces: %d", nl, nt, ns);

    
    return 0;
}
```

Gives me different huge and wrongs numbers based on how I provide data to program?

Using `./a.out` and typing "a" in terminal, followed by Ctrl + D:

```
Lines: -621574383, Tabs: 0, Spaces: 32765
```

Using `cat input.txt | ./a.out`, with input.txt containing "a" and nothing more:

```
Lines: -115774576, Tabs: 0, Spaces: 32765
```

Using `./a.out <<< echo 'a'`:

```
Lines: 1775654849, Tabs: 0, Spaces: 32767
```

VSCode Debugger also shows huge numbers even after assign 0 to the variables.

[image: VSCode debug view]

Obs:

- I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
- I compiled the program with gcc version 9.3.0.
- Using zsh instead of bash (Although to use bash also does not work, just changes a little bit the huge number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration:

```
int c, nl, ns, nt = 0;
```

Only initializes `nt`.  To initialize `nl` and `ns` as well, you need:

```
int c, nl = 0, ns = 0, nt = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Only variable `nt` is initialized.  Variables `c`, `nl` and `ns` are uninitialized.  You can avoid this by declaring them on separate lines and initializing individually to zero or adding `= 0` after each.

[How can I declare and define multiple variables in one line using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838408/how-can-i-declare-and-define-multiple-variables-in-one-line-using-c/6838447)