# Inserting a number into a circular queue causes an infinite loop

Tags: c, queue, infinite-loop, circular-queue

I'm working on a C program that implements a queue, and I'm encountering an issue with an infinite loop.

The program is supposed to perform insertion, traversal, and deletion operations on the queue.

However, I'm observing that the program enters into an infinite loop under certain conditions.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 10

int queue[N];
int front = -1;
int rear = -1;

void insert();
void traverse();
void delete();

int main() {
    insert();
    traverse();
    delete();
    return 0;
}

void insert() {
    int item;
    if ((rear + 1) % N == front) {
        printf("overflow");
    } else if (front == -1 && rear == -1) {
        scanf("%d", &item);
        rear, front = 0;
        queue[rear] = item;
    } else {
        scanf("%d", &item);
        rear = (rear + 1) % N;
        queue[rear] = item;
    }
}

void delete() {
    int item;
    if (rear == -1 && front == -1) {
        printf("underflow");
    } else if (rear == front) {
        rear, front = -1;
    } else {
        item = queue[front];
        front = (front + 1) % N;
    }
}

void traverse() {
    int i = front;
    if (front == -1 && rear == -1) {
        printf("underflow");
    } else {
        while (i != rear) {
            printf("%d", queue[i]);
            i = (i + 1) % N;
        }
        printf("%d", queue[i]);
    }
}
```

I am trying to input a number in the queue but instead of displaying that number, it is getting into an infinite loop.

I am using VS Code.

Comment: Under what exact conditions does your program enter an infinite loop? *For example:* what sequence of actions (inserting, deleting and traversing) did you perform in what order, and what specific values did you insert into the queue?

Comment: I'm asking this because I have implemented your exact same data structure (although not in C, which I'm not familiar with) and not been able to reproduce the infinite loop with any sequence of actions I've tested. https://www.mediafire.com/file/fqkceoy4q4rtfg7/QueueTest.html/file

Comment: The typical problem with a queue is the full/empty ambiguity when only using two pointers (*head* and *tail*). Also: There are at several hundred implementations of queues around; why not look at one of those? Also learn how to debug and how to use `assert()`.

Answer (score 2):

The infinite loop is because `rear` is permanently set to -1 only. The issue is with this line of C code in your `insert()` function, which is supposed to set both `rear` and `front` to 0 when an element is inserted into the empty queue:

```
 rear, front = 0;
```

The above statement may not work as you think it does. Only `front` will be set to 0. I have used `gcc` compiler on Linux and it will not assign 0 to `rear` with such a statement. I am not sure what your VS Code compiler does with such a statement. You can try to `printf` the value of `rear` during an insertion of an element during the empty queue condition in VS Code and see if `rear` gets changed at all while executing the code.

Change the code in your `insert()` function to:

```
rear = front = 0;
```

The above should remove the infinite loop you are seeing.

For more clarity, you may like to check a previous Q&A on this same issue:
[How can I declare and define multiple variables in one line using C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838408/how-can-i-declare-and-define-multiple-variables-in-one-line-using-c)

Comment: Even better, change it to two lines:  `rear = 0;` and `front = 0;`.  Absolutely **nothing** is gained from cramming both those into one line.

Comment: Nice answer! That also explains why I wasn't able to reproduce the problem in HTML/JS: that multiple-variable-assignment syntax gave an error so I changed it to two separate statements separated by a semicolon. It never occurred to me to question whether the original statement worked as intended in **c**.