Defining Pointer Types C++
I was writing a small program to work with pointers and came across strange compiler behavior.
First case:
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* a,b;
    
    std::cout << typeid(&a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(&b).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

In the first case, the program output will be like this:
PPi
Pi

Which, as far as I understand, means that a pointer to "a" will be of type "int**", while a pointer to "b" will be of type "int*"
This seems strange to me and I can't understand why it works this way.
Second case:
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int* a;
    int* b;

    std::cout << typeid(&a).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(&b).name() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

Second output:
PPi
PPi

And in this case, pointers receive the types that, in theory, should have received in the first case.
I have no idea where to look for information about this. There was nothing about this in the book I learned C++ from.

In your first example, b is int not int*. So &b will be int* not int**. If you want to declare two pointers in one line in your first example, you need to declare it like this: int *a, *b;

That's a legacy from C. Don't declare, define more than one object at a line.

declare one variable per line: int* a;  int b;

This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6838408/how-can-i-declare-and-define-multiple-variables-in-one-line-using-c has some extra discussion which might be useful.

In the declaration syntax * binds more closely to the variable name than it does to int. So it's like int (*a), b; not (int*) a, b; (the last is not legal syntax, but you get the point). For this reason some style guides say you should space the declaration like this int *a, b; but I think the one declaration per line rule is better way to make this clear.

Dupe: Type Declaration - Pointer Asterisk Position and Declaring multiple object pointers on one line

"I have no idea where to look for information about this. There was nothing about this in the book I learned C++ from...." That is why it is important to use a good c++ book. One of the best c++ books is named C++ Primer by Stanley lippman 5th edition. You can use that.

The declaration syntax comprises of a declaration specifier followed by a declarator list.
In your case, you have the simple type specifier int and a list of two declarators: *a and b.
The * prefix turns the first declarator into a pointer declarator.
The type of a is int*, and the type of b is int.
If you want both to be pointers, you would write:
int *a, *b;

